# How to delete S3 object using bamboo plan/script to delete S3 object using bamboo

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bamboo

I want to delete S3 files from the bucket by creating a bamboo plan/script which when run will delete the file.

I tried creating a plan and then creating a task. But in the task i can see no option for Amazon S3 Object in the list.
I have refered to the below url and followed the steps:
https://utoolity.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TAWS/pages/19464196/Using+the+Amazon+S3+Object+task+in+Bamboo

Is there any other way i can create a bamboo plan and delete files from S3???

Answer (score 1):

The link in the question is to a paid 3rd party Bamboo plugin ([link here](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211585/tasks-for-aws-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview)) and not installed by default.

You currently have 2 options for AWS and Bamboo Integration:

1. Purchase the Tasks for AWS Bamboo plugin.
2. Create a script task that uses the AWS S3 API or AWS SDK to achieve what you are trying to do ([Amazon's REST Delete S3 Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html)).

Comment: Hi Wesley, Can we delete the S3 file through normal script like bash/shell script in bamboo by selecting Script task while creating a task?

Comment: Yes.  But you may need to setup the CLI or import any libraries your script uses onto the Bamboo agents that will execute the task.  Example s3 cli commands: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2019/04/aws-s3-cli-examples/